# How do I assign a relative path of an embed image to a ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture.FileName?

Tags: c#

There are 2 SSCCEs for this:

## 1.

I have added a picture to my VSTO document-level add-in by right clicking the solution -> add -> existing item -> myPic.jpg.

Now I am working with an Excel spreadsheet and want to add a picture to the top left header. Using [PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture.FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194861(v=office.15).aspx) and providing an *absolute* path to the picture it loads just fine while debugging.

When I am trying to change the path to not-absolute and say something like

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture.FileName = "\\Assets\\myPic.jpg"
```

I keep getting a `HRESULT: 0x800A03EC` exception.

[image]

I think I am not getting the correct syntax for to access the `Assets\myPic.jpg`.

## 2.

I have added a new resource, selected an existing item and selected the myPic.jpg. I can access it via `Resource1.myPic` but [ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pagesetup.leftheaderpicture(v=office.15).aspx) is **read-only**...

The [PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture.FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194861(v=office.15).aspx) needs a `string` type parameter and I am not sure how to retrieve the path to my already embed resource...

## Q:

How do I embed a picture in my solution as a resource (or just an existing item) to be able to use it with [PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture.FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194861(v=office.15).aspx)?

Comment: @rene the current working directory is `C:\Users\admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ScreeningTemplate\ScreeningTemplate\bin\Debug` as I am debugging the project.

Comment: You are trying `@"Assets\myPic.jpg"` aren't you?

Comment: @rene yes I have tried it. Still getting an exception

Comment: I would almost suggest to use ProcessMonitor to see the actual path it is trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, I have solved it.

Added an existing item `myPic.jpg` to the solution and set `Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always` (*but I am sure you can set it to copy if newer*)

[image]

Note: *With this setup your file always gets "copied" to the published directory.*

[image]

Now all you need in your code is

```
ws.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture.Filename = 
                           AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\myPic.jpg";
ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&G";
```

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is very well explained [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path/6041505#6041505)

and the end result as expected

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From my experience adding files to a project will embed them into your `.exe`. That means you can not refer them by using a file path. You can however read them.

If you want your file to placed outside the `.exe` file you should just add it your project then right click on it and select properties. Set the `Copy to output directory` property to `Always copy`. Your file will be copied into the build folder under the same folder structure. Now you can refer your file with a relative path.

If you really need to get that picture from the resource file you could save it as a temporary file (using `Path.GetTempFileName`) then load it via file path.

Comment: Oops I deleted my last comment instead of editing... Can you give an example of relative path syntax so that I don't get an exception?

Comment: `@"\Assets\myPic.jpg"` or without the @  `"\\Assets\\myPic.jpg"`

Comment: both fail with the same exception type.

Comment: Try the full path then. Use `Path.GetFullPath` also try to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714626/exception-from-hresult-0x800a03ec-error

Comment: tried it with the `Path.GetFullPath` already. Updated the question with a screenshot of the exception/

Comment: the strange thing is that `Path.GetFullPath("\\Assets\\myPic.jpg")` returns `C:\Assets\myPic.jpg` like if it didn't recognize the current folder structure :///

Comment: Try to combine with `Enviroment.CurrentFolder` then

Comment: There is no exception where the path is hardcoded, the problem is that neither debug or release actually copy the image to it's destination folder

Comment: *`Set the Copy to output directory property to Always copy. Your file will be copied into the build folder under the same folder structure.`* but it's not copied :/ I think there might be a bug within VS