# UDF works in VBA, returns #REF! in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a function that calculates the sales for 2014 for the specific worksheets inside the workbook, then prints the total sales for 2014 in a specific cell. 
I can call the function inside of VBA, no issue. But if try to use the function in the workbook, I get a reference error. I know #REF! means the formula refers to a cell that isn't valid, do I need to be returning some kind of value into the cell that I am trying to call the function into? For example, if I type sum2014("A1151") into cell F25, do I need to be returning some kind of boolean value for the function to work properly?

```
Function sum2014(someaccount As String) As Currency
Dim i As Integer
Dim total As Currency
Dim ws As Worksheet
total = 0
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(someaccount)
     For i = 1 To 50
          If ws.Range("A3").Offset(i, 0) >= DateValue("January 1, 2014") And ws.Range("A3").Offset(i, 0) <= DateValue("December 1, 2014") Then
          total = total + ws.Range("A3").Offset(i, 1)
          sum2014 = total
          End If
     Next
     If Worksheets("New Charges").Range("C3").Offset(i, 0) = someaccount Then
          Worksheets("New Charges").Range("E3").Offset(i, 0) = total
     End If
     For i = 1 To 5
          If Worksheets("New Charges").Range("C3").Offset(i, 0).Value = someaccount Then
          Worksheets("New Charges").Range("E3").Offset(i, 0).Value = total
          End If
     Next  

End Function
```

Example of calling the function inside VBA:

```
Sub testfunction()
sum2014 ("A1151")
sum2014 ("B1808")
sum2014 ("C3711")
sum2014 ("D3265")
End Sub
```

I can call the function inside VBA, and it works fine. The sales are calculated and placed in the proper location. But I cannot call the UDF inside of the workbook. I am calling the function with

```
 sum2014=("A1151")
```

Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I could probably clean up the function with do while or do until loops instead of for loops but for right now I would just like to get the function working inside of the workbook then revisit rewriting later.

Comment: you can't have a UDF change a sheet in any place other than the calling cell

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you, my UDF cannot change a value except in the cell I input the UDF into? So if I put my UDF in say cell A25, but want to return the value of total sales into cell E3, I can't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it is correct that a function called from a sheet [may not change sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053254/difference-between-call-and-other-means-of-running-a-sub-in-visual-basic#comment52006245_32053254) (and you may [run into problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52698777/excel-office-365-restarts-automatically-while-executing-udf#comment92324771_52698777) if you try to use a trick to work around it), your immediate problem is that `sum2014` is a valid Excel range address (column 13403 (`SUM`), row 2014), hence the `#REF!` error when you try to do `=SUM2014("A1151")`. It's the same as if your function was called `A1`.

A name usable in a formula may not look like a valid Excel range. Pick another name (and make sure you don't change other cells from that function, otherwise it will be a `#VAL!` error).

If you need to change various cells from a routine, make it a sub and call it from an external event, such as a button press or a `Worksheet_Change` handler, but not from a formula in a cell.