# Why would my Excel 2010 UDF quit working with a #NAME? error?

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel 2010. A couple of months ago I wrote some UDF's and got them debugged and working. Today I changed a value in the spreadsheet, and suddenly all the UDF's displayed #NAME?

Ultimately I decided to start from scratch. I created a new workbook with just one UDF. Here it is, in it's entirety:

```
Function say7() As Integer
    say7 = 7
End Function
```

I then went to Sheet1 and in box A1 entered "=say7()". I got "#NAME?".

If I type "sa", the dropdown shows "say7". I can press tab or enter and it fills in the function name. And then it says #NAME?.

I understand that Excel 2010 is no longer supported. Did Microsoft do something to break UDFs?

My XLSM was working a few weeks ago. Indeed, the file where I made the change was a copy of the original spreadsheet. I went back to the original, changed a value in one cell that should have forced a recalculation, and it said #NAME?. I didn't change the code, I didn't change any settings, nothing. The only thing I changed was one data value and somehow that makes the function name not be recognized anymore.

Update: Several posters have pointed out that "say7" is not a legal name for a function in Excel and that using this name would produce a #REF? error. True. But my problem was that I was getting a #NAME? error, not a #REF? error. In my attempt to create a simplified scenario -- to make sure that the problem wasn't some error within the function -- I created a new, deliberately very simple function that got the same #NAME? error. Yes, I gave this function an illegal name, which muddles my question. I apologize for the confusion. Explaining why say7 is an invalid name is interesting and useful information, but sadly does not solve my original problem.

Comment: You cannot have a worksheet function (entered on the worksheet) whose name is identical to a cell reference (in either the A1 or R1C1 styles)..  `=say7_()` would be OK.  But a UDF with that name should have also failed in Excel 2010.  Did your 2010 UDF have the same name?  And was it being applied to a worksheet?  Or just used in a VBA routine?

Comment: Are you sure you got `#NAME?`? You should be getting `#REF!` (confirmed on Excel 2010 specifically). `#NAME?` instead of the UDF results most often occurs when you disable macros in Excel. You've probably done that without realising it, or there is now a group policy at your place that allows macros in files coming only from secure locations.

Comment: [Closure being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404532/522444)

Comment: @GSerg No, I am quite certain that it is #NAME? Yes, I considered the possibility that i had accidentally changed some global setting. This is on my home computer so there shouldn't be any "group policy" -- I'm the only person who uses this computer and it's not on a company network. In any case, I think I found the solution but now that the question has been closed I can't post it.

Comment: @Jay You can now. I do wonder what it is.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You are correct, say7 is not a legal function name, and using that name for my test program muddled the situation by introducing a new, unrelated error. The function name in my original program, that mysteriously failed after working for months, was "dist3". Which appears to be legal because it worked originally.

Answer (score 5):

When you are writing the function then there are conventional rules of naming it. One of them says

> You should not use any names that are identical to the functions, statements, and methods in Visual Basic because you may shadow the same keywords in the language.

The name `Say7` while it looks innocuous enough, clashes with a column numbered 12895 which is named as `SAY`. So in principle, below works for me but I do not have Excel 2010 to see and confirm.

```
Public Function SaySeven() As Integer
    SaySeven = 7
End Function
```

---

**Edit:**

After reading OP's own answer post and other details over, I can think of one more situation where we may encounter `#NAME` error. This can be reproduced fairly easily.

**Step 1:** Create a UDF and save the workbook. When you do so, it should not be saved at Excel's trusted locations and the file shall not be identified as trusted. If it is trusted then Excel doesn't prompt for enabling active content. At the point of creation, Excel will produce results without any error. Now close the workbook.

**Step 2:** Reopen this workbook. You will be prompted with below message.
[image]

Ignore this message i.e. do not press "Enable Content" button. OP may have missed this message somewhere.

**Step 3:** If the UDF was implemented in the previous session and it has returned a valid result then it will not return any error upon recalculation. However, if you enter this UDF in a new cell then Excel will return `#NAME` error. In below snapshot, both green cell and yellow cell contain exactly the same formula i.e.

`=dist3()`

[image]

But the outcome differs.

So in conclusion: UDF name `dist3` is valid and it should work as cited by OP in his later postings. However, in above specific case, one may encounter error of this kind. It will, however, apply to all UDFs and not just `dist3`.

> I have tested this in Excel's `Office 365` version but I don't think there will be any major differences in this behavior across versions.

Comment: I can confirm your answer. Just tested it in Office365, Excel 2016, version 2008 (Build 13127.20910).

Comment: Just to add some confusion, you could use a function name like `=sa7()` if the function is only being used in VBA. It is only invalid when entered into a worksheet cell.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the correct answer. I've got to go back and look for the "macros ok" message. I'm not sure if I was just blind and missed it, or if there was some reason why it didn't display. I have a theory that maybe the "excel 2010 is no longer supported" message was displayed on top of it so I didn't see it, but whatever.

Comment: @Jay If that's the case then I do not see any reason why it should not work when you reopen the file where you encountered this error in new Excel session. Excel will prompt you to enable content. If you open Excel file and ignore the prompt then it disappears after some time.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually partly figured it out. At least enough to get it working.

Excel normally blocks you from running UDF's unless you explicitly give it permission. When you try to use the first UDF it pops up a question at the top of the window asking for permission, and if you don't give it, then UDFs aren't recognized and you get #NAME? errors for them.

Apparently -- and this is the part I'm not sure about -- the message telling me that support for Excel 2010 had expired was displayed on top of this message so I couldn't see it. Or something like that. I copied the file to another computer that had a newer version of Excel and I got the message. I clicked OK and the UDFs worked. I then saved it and copied it back to the original computer and it worked fine.

As I had previously clicked Ok on this and this answer is apparently saved with the file, I'm not sure why it asked again. Maybe some changes to the file invalidate the previous answer? I'm not sure.

I created a new file and saw the message about "UDFs ok?" on that one. So maybe my theory that the message was covered by the expiration notice is not correct. I guess it's possible that the message was there all along and I was just blind and didn't see it. That seems unlikely as I was searching for some explanation, but, etc.

In my first version of this post I said that the function name "say7" worked. This was incorrect. When I got the spreadsheet to work I had gone back to my original spreadsheet, where the function that was referenced in the spreadsheet was called "dist3", which works. (There were other functions but they wee all called from within dist3.)

In any case, before I created "say7" I was trying to get it to work with a function called "dist3" and that was also failing with the #NAME?. And as I said in the question, it worked a month ago and I didn't change any function names, so I knew that an illegal function name was not the issue. My attempt to create a simple function to test the problem was a wrong turn because I used an illegal function name that created different problems.

Comment: The function name `say7` [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53134715/11683) work. It always causes a `#REF!` error in Excel 2007 or newer when called from a sheet. It will only work [in Excel 2003](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq1NO.png) or older, because these versions are limited to 256 columns, and thus `say` is not a valid column name there. There is no "UDFs ok?" message either; the macro security in Office 2010 is implemented as [a yellow bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCWMx.png) that does not display modally.

Comment: @GSerg When I said there's a "UDF's ok?" message, yes, I meant the yellow bar. I'm not sure what you mean when you say there is no such message and then in the next sentence describe the message. I didn't say it was a modal pop up. It certainly was not. If it had been modal, I wouldn't have been able to fail to answer it and then wonder why nothing worked.

Comment: @GSerg RE the name "say7": You're correct, that gives a #REF? error. My statement that this name worked was incorrect. When I got the spreadsheet to work I had gone back to my original spreadsheet where the function was named "dist3", and that works fine in Excel 2010 and 2013.

Comment: So in the end, it's what I [originally suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65746707/why-would-my-excel-2010-udf-quit-working-with-a-name-error-not-a-ref-error/65793395?noredirect=1#comment116270646_65746707) - the function name does not work with a `#REF!` (hence the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53134535/11683) that you [called to be removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404532/11683)), and the `#NAME?` error is due to disabled macros?

Comment: @gserg Hmm, I'm not trying to make an argument about this. I was trying to get help with a problem. I freely admit that my question was muddled because in my attempt to create a simplified scenario to test solutions I introduced a new and unrelated problem. But sorry, no, the answer you linked to did not address my problem. The fact that, under different circumstances, i.e. if I had checked the "UDF ok?" box, I would have gotten a different error message, doesn't explain why I got the error message that I did get.

Comment: To say, "When I tried this I got a different error message, and here's the explanation for that other error message" is a fair point to bring up. Yes, one could imagine the possibility that I was confused about the error message. But I wasn't. I correctly stated what the error was, and the other answer you cited did not address that error. Again, I'm not trying to attack you. I appreciate your effort to help. It's just that, in this case, you made a faulty assumption, that I must be mis-stating what the error message was, and so in fact your suggestion did not address my real problem.

Comment: I am little perplexed by your explanation. Do you still have the file where `dist3` doesn't work? Is it possible to strip any sensitive data it may have and then post a link to the file.

Comment: Well, it works now, but it originally got the #NAME? error whether the function was called "say7" or "dist3". BTW I didn't post the original, not because it contained any proprietary information, but just because it was big and somewhat complex and I was trying to get the minimum file that had the same problem.

Comment: Okay, I have posted an edit in my answer post. Please see if that helps answer your query.

Answer (score -2):

Seeing the logic of @shrivallbha redij's reply I changed the function's name to SAYG (with the idea that G defines the 7th column) and still got a #NAME error. However this can be avoided by passing an argument in the function call, even if the argument isn't used by the function or if it's blank.

`=SAYG` -  returns an error

`=SAYG(A1)`  - returns 7

`=SAYG()`  - returns 7

Comment: If you write `=SAYG`, Excel will think it is a named range and try to evaluate accordingly. Providing a bracket with empty argument as `=SAYG()` is the way Excel understands it as a function and this applies to default functions in Excel as well e.g. writing `=ROW' function will return the same #NAME error as it does for UDF you have created. This is the reason in your case and it is little different from OP's case.