# Error while using xlswrite

Tags: excel, matlab

When I run the following code

```
function feff

filename = 'UHL DEA.xlsx';
FI = xlsread(filename,'AU9:AU179');
FO = xlsread(filename,'AW9:AW179');
FEff = FI./FO;

%Write the efficiency back to the appropriate file in excel

xlswrite(filename,FEff,'BC9:BC179');
```

I get the error

```
 Error using xlswrite (line 220)
 Excel returned: Error: Object returned error code: 0x800A03EC.

 Error in feff (line 15)
 xlswrite(filename,FEff,'BC9:BC179');
```

But it works fine if i write into another file as follows

```
function feff

filename = 'UHL DEA.xlsx';
FI = xlsread(filename,'AU9:AU179');
FO = xlsread(filename,'AW9:AW179');
FEff = FI./FO;

%Write the efficiency back to the appropriate file in excel

xlswrite('DEA.xlsx',FEff,'BC9:BC179');
```

The UHL DEA.xlsx contains other data in the previous columns and I need to write this data again in the same file. Pointers will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: maybe `xlswrite` cannot write into an open file? try to close the excel.

Comment: @Serg Have tried doing that but no success

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a backward compatible xls file?
[HRESULT: 0x800A03EC on Worksheet.range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099770/hresult-0x800a03ec-on-worksheet-range)

Check the accepted answer.

Edit: If this is not it, what happens if you try to edit the entire range without using matlab?