# How to add values, containing double quotes, from DataTable rows values to Excel cells formulas?

Tags: c#, excel-formula, string-conversion

I'm newbie in C#.
I tried to insert strings from DataTable into Excel cells formulas, but unsuccesfully.
For example, I have

> =ROUND(R[-2]C*IF(R[-1]C="";R[-1]C17;R[-1]C)/(IF(R[-1]C="";R[-1]C17;R[-1]C));2)

as value.
I also tried to make

> =ROUND(R[-2]C*IF(R[-1]C=\"\";R[-1]C17;R[-1]C)/(IF(R[-1]C=\"\";R[-1]C17;R[-1]C));2)

But I got an exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
In the last example debugger shows proper string, but I also got that exception.

Also, it works, when I put this code:

> Globals.Wirksheet1.Cells.Range["A100"].Value2 =
>   @"=ROUND(R[-2]C*IF(R[-1]C="""",R[-1]C17,R[-1]C)/(IF(R[-1]C="""",R[-1]C17,R[-1]C)),2)";

But I need to get values from DataTable, also I don't know how to add @ to string.
Please, explain me how to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099770/hresult-0x800a03ec-on-worksheet-range

Comment: Thanks, but it is not my case. The problem with mycode is converting double quotes to Excel formulas.

Comment: I solved it on Excel side :) I changed values in my Table Data to =ROUND(R[-2]C*IF(R[-1]C=CONCATENATE(CHAR(34),CHAR(34)),R[-1]C17,R[-1]C)/(IF(R[-1]C=CONCATENATE(CHAR(34),CHAR(34)),R[-1]C17,R[-1]C)),2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of an answer.

OP has stated:

> I changed values in my Table Data to
>
> =ROUND(R[-2]C*IF(R[-1]C=CONCATENATE(CHAR(34),CHAR(34)),R[-1]C17,R[-1]C)/(IF(R[-1‌​]C=CONCATENATE(CHAR(34),CHAR(34)),R[-1]C17,R[-1]C)),2)