# Consultation about convert dataSet to Excel

Tags: c#, excel

i have this code for transfer from dataSet to Excel (xlsx)

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;    

string SQL = "SELECT Store,Zitur FROM CounterG group by Store,Zitur";

var dsView = new DataSet();
using (var adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, Conn))
    adp.Fill(dsView, "CounterG");

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
xla.Visible = false;

Workbook wb = xla.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);

Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)xla.ActiveSheet;
ws.Name = "Tab1";

int i = 1;
foreach (DataRow comp in dsView.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    ws.Cells[i, 1] =  comp[0].ToString();
    ws.Cells[i, 2] =  comp[1].ToString();
    i++;
}

if (File.Exists(@"d\DDD.xlsx"))
    File.Delete(@"d:\DDD.xlsx");

//xla.SaveWorkspace(@"d:\DDD.xlsx");
xla.Save(@"d:\DDD.xlsx");
```

But I got the error "*Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC*" on this line:  `xla.Save(@"d:\DDD.xlsx");`

I work on WinForm with .NET Framework 2.0.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099770/hresult-0x800a03ec-on-worksheet-range) question may help - check the accepted answer

Comment: I'd suggest using [NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/) instead which makes the application independent of Office.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Workbook.SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas.aspx) instead, as following.  Also you need to include [Excel.Quit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.quit%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to release the file.

```
//xla.SaveWorkspace(@"d:\DDD.xlsx");
wb.SaveAs(Filename: @"d:\DDD.xlsx", FileFormat: XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);

xla.Quit(); // Exit Excel releasing the file
```

---

As per the documentation, you should not use [Excel.Application.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.save%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to create the file:

> The first time you save a workbook, use the
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook.SaveAs()
>   method to specify a name for the file.