# Interop excel doesn't copy charts using vb.net on windows8

Tags: vb.net, excel, charts, office-interop

I'm building a program that makes excel based reports using xlsx files using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library and Visual Studio 2010.

I have a xlsx file with 2 charts, and some styles. Using...

```
Dim LibroExcel As Excel.Workbook
Dim HojaExcel() As Excel.Worksheet

LibroExcel.Worksheets(1).copy(After:=LibroExcel.Worksheets(i))

HojaExcel(i) = LibroExcel.Worksheets.Item(i + 1)
```

... I copy that sheet to another sheet until the for instruction I use ends.

**The problem:** In a system with Windows8 when I use this function, the charts are not copied from one sheet to the next one. But if I do the same on a Windows 7  system, it works. Both systems are using the same version of Excel.

Comment: Do you get any error in the code? Did you try to debug the code?

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching on the internet, and following the steps on the next post i have resolved my problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13174856/4587472

Also i applied the next steps because the first time i didn't found **Microsoft Excel Application**:
On 64 bit system with 32 bit Office try this:

1. Start
2. Run
3. mmc -32
4. File
5. Add Remove Snap-in
6. Component Services
7. Add
8. OK
9. Console Root
10. Component Services
11. Computers
12. My Computer
13. DCOM Config
14. Microsoft Excel Application

Anyway, can someone explain what this steps really do? (This steps and the post steps)