# How can i export the Dates?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagrid

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)Excel.ActiveSheet;
        Excel.Visible = true;

        ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Tarih";
        ws.Cells[1, 2] = "Kasiyer";
        ws.Cells[1, 3] = "Ucret";
        ws.Cells[1, 4] = "Bilet No";
        ws.Cells[1, 5] = "Firma Adı";
        for (int j = 2; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                ws.Cells[j,i]=dataGridView1.Rows[j-2].Cells[i-1].Value;
            }
        }
```

Dates are not coming to First Cell in Excel . How can i do that ? please help me ? And also i have got a warning like "HRESULT özel durum döndürdü: 0x800AC472"

Comment: Have you debugged it? What are the values of `dataGridView1.Rows[j-2].Cells[i-1].Value`?

Comment: Values are dates , cashier , charge , ticketnumber and company name . Dates are not export to excel

Answer (score 0):

You can't probably take date value, it returns null and gives an error. Just for date column, you try to convert.

```
for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        ws.Cells[i,0] = (Convert.ToDateTime(ws.Cells[i,0]).ToOADate();
    }
```

Additionaly you can try that too.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
range = range.get_Resize(rowCount, columnCount);
range.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY";
```

Comment: Program tells me  "HRESULT özel durum döndürdü: 0x800A03EC "

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099770/hresult-0x800a03ec-on-worksheet-range). @SercanDeveci