# VB.net Exception de HRESULT : 0x800A03EC ( Excel)

Tags: .net, excel

I do not understand why this line make me an error:

> TFeuille.Cells ( 10 , 7) = SommeJoursVent + " ; 2) " ''SommeJourVent==ARRONDI(SOMME(T2;Y2;AD2;AI2;AN2;AS2;AX2;BC2;BH2;BM2;BR2;BW2;CB2;CG2;CL2;CQ2;CV2;DA2;DF2;DK2;DP2;DU2;DZ2;EE2;EJ2;EO2;ET2;EY2;FD2;FI2;FN2;FS2;FX2;GC2;GH2;GM2;GR2;GW2;HB2;HG2;HL2;HQ2;HV2;IA2;IF2;IK2;IP2;IU2).

exception:

> Exception de HRESULT : 0x800A03EC ( Excel)

knowing that I am using a .net framework 4.0 and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 15.0.0.0 , I'm already doing that on a windows application that I have developed with Framework 3.5 and Microsoft Excel Interop 14.0.0.0 .. this has run well.

Comment: That looks like it's a document range issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099770/hresult-0x800a03ec-on-worksheet-range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This: `==` is not valid in an Excel formula. Use `=` instead.

Excel formulas are similar to BASIC and use `=` for equal-to, and `<>` for not-equal-to.

Answer (score 1):

I try this :
TFeuille.Cells ( 2 , 7) = "Test " it works ..

I do this TFeuille.Cells ( 2 , 7) = " = ARRONDI ( SOMME ( (C2) ) ; 1) " and it works no .. the hand and when I do it takes me 2008