# How can i import my ListBox to Excel with C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, import

I wanna import my ListBox in a Excel File. But i keep getting this error HRESULT: 0x800A03EC can someone help me i googled it but couldnt find anything

My code

```
        string ExcelFileLocation = (@"C:\Users\bra\Desktop\EXCELFILe");


        Excel.Application oApp;
        Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
        Excel.Workbook oBook;


        oApp = new Excel.Application();
        oBook = oApp.Workbooks.Add();
        oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet) oBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        int i = 0;
        i++;

        for (int j = 0; j < listBox1.Items.Count; j++)
        {
            oSheet.Cells[j, 1] = listBox1.Items;

        }
        oBook.SaveAs(ExcelFileLocation);
        oBook.Close();
        oApp.Quit();
```

my ListBox items

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("TEST1");
            listBox1.Items.Add("TEST2");
            listBox1.Items.Add("TEST3");

        }
```

Comment: Which line throws the error? Also, you should probably add a ".xls" or ".xlsx" extension to your file name.

Comment: More info here too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13174856/1202807

Comment: @GabrielLuci the foor loop does and where should i add the xls or xlsl???

Comment: @m.h.p To your ExcelFileLocation

Comment: @Bas bij het begin of einde ?

Comment: @m.h.p at the end.

Comment: @Bas can u give a example

Comment: string ExcelFileLocation = (@"C:\Users\bra\Desktop\EXCELFILe.xlsx"); I am not sure if this is what @GabrielLuci meant. He can answer more of your questions.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant.

Comment: Take a look at that link I posted above. There are a bunch of answers there. It seems this error can happen for several reasons, so one of those answers might help.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Both doenst work, but i will look at the link thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your variable "j" must begin at **1** not 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to assign *the set of all items* (i.e. `ListBox.Items`) to each and every cell in Excel.

What you probably meant to do is something like

```
for (int j = 0; j < listBox1.Items.Count; j++)
{
    oSheet.Cells[j + 1, 1] = listBox1.Items[j].ToString(); // Notice the [j] indexer
}
```

More importantly, excel indexes start at 1, like @mdelpeix rightfully noticed. That is most likely what is throwing the particular exception your question is about, so his answer should probably get the answer mark :)