# Windows 10 COMException HRESULT:0X800A03EC while saving Excel file

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop, hresult

I have a VB.Net windows forms application which is working fine in windows 7 environment.

Now, I want to upgrade to windows 10. So I have started to test my application in windows 10 server machine.

I am getting an `Exception` (Exception from HRESULT:0X800A03EC) while saving a dynamically generated file in one of the folders on server.

I have identified the issue is not with the permissions.

```
'getting exception at this line of code.
xlApp.Workbooks(1).SaveAs(filename , xl.XlFileFormat.xlHtml)
```

Code for reference:

```
Private Sub VierwInBrowser(ByVal xlApp As xl.Application)
    Dim fileName As String = String.Format("{0}\{1}", "C:\Data", GetUniqueFileName())
Try
    xlApp.Workbooks(1).SaveAs(fileName, xl.XlFileFormat.xlHtml)
Catch ex as Exception
Messagebox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
    xlApp.Quit()
    xlApp = Nothing
    GC.Collect()
    browser.Visible = True
    browser.Navigate(fileName)
    browser.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, can you please post the block of code that is causing the exception ? This will help us help you...

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank You for your response... I am getting the exception at the this line of code                                                                     xlApp.Workbooks(1).SaveAs(filename , xl.XlFileFormat.xlHtml) //geting exception at this line. Please look at the link I shared in my post

Comment: Yes I saw the picture. I was mentionning the block of code that leads to this exception.

Comment: Please check the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7108420/5897829

Comment: I have gone through the above solution. But still getting same exception .

Comment: What is the value of `fileName` when you receive the error?  Is it a valid file path that the program has access permission to?

Comment: Have you checked that `GetUniqueFileName` is returning a string in the correct format  - also that there is no backslash in the returned string

Comment: Hello ,@TnTinMn - yes filename is a valid path and it has access persmission also.                                                                                                            @David - GetUniqueFileName returning correct string

Answer (score 0):

I have identified that the issue is with **converting the excel sheet to html page** in windows 10.

For this I have found a solution at https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/922850/error-message-in-office-when-a-file-is-blocked-by-registry-policy-sett