# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC when setting value of a cell (through Powershell)

Tags: excel, powershell, excel-automation

I am trying to set a value to an excel cell through Powershell, and I am getting the error HRESULT: 0x800A03EC, which ends the script prematurely. I realize there have been other questions relating to this error or similar, but none of the solutions have worked for me, so I am assuming this is a separate problem.

I have run my script before but it is only now giving me this error.

Relevant code:

```
$Output_Location = "Z:\Documents\Powershell"
$Excel_File = "Report.xlsx"
$ExcelWorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.open("$Output_Location\$Excel_File")
$MainSheet = $ExcelWorkBook.worksheets.Item("Report")
$Sheet1 = $ExcelWorkBook.worksheets.Item("Sheet1")
$Sheet1.name = "Statistics" 
$StatisticsSheet = $ExcelWorkBook.worksheets.Item("Statistics")

$row = 3
$column = 2
$StatisticsSheet.Cells.Item(2,2)= 'KeyToMatch'
$StatisticsSheet.Cells.Item($row,$column) = '=COUNTIFS(Report!E2:E200000,B$3,Report!G2:G200000,"UserMailbox")'
$row++
$StatisticsSheet.Cells.Item($row,$column) = '=COUNTIFS(Report!E2:E200000,B$3,Report!G2:G200000,"RemoteUserMailbox")'
$row++
```

The code loads up the excel file and hits the line which sets the cell (2,2)/(B,2) to its value just fine. But when the code hits the line setting the cell value the row below the KeyToMatch (B,3), it throws the error 0x800A03EC.

Full error:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
At Z:\Documents\Powershell\Reporting\Report.ps1:113 char:1
+ $StatisticsSheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).value = '=COUNTIFS(Report! ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

I have tried spacing out the '=' between the cell and value, I have also tried the following:

```
$StatisticsSheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).value = ...
$StatisticsSheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).value2 = ...
$StatisticsSheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).text = ...
$StatisticsSheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).formula = ...
```

I can comment out any number of lines which set the cell's value to a formula and the first one to attempt to do so will throw the mentioned error.

Like I said, I have run this script before but it is only now giving me troubles. How can I fix this so the code runs smoothly?

Comment: Your code works fine for me on PowerShell 5.1 and Excel 2013. What versions are you using? Have you checked out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099770/hresult-0x800a03ec-on-worksheet-range)? I see you have `.xlsx` in your code but that's not necessarily the file format. Try with a range of `E2:E2000` to see if same error occurs. Also, `$Excel.Visible = $true` may be helpful for debugging.

Comment: @gms0ulman I am using Powershell 5.0.10586.117 and Excel 2013. When I select properties on the (unfinished) automated excel file (after the program exits), it says file type of .xlsx. I use $Excel.visible = $true but did not include it to save clutter in my question - which is how I know the program partially completes the automation. I followed the steps in the question you linked but got the same result when I tested again. Any idea as to why it throws this error on my system?

Comment: @gms0ulman I tested with range E2:E2000 and it threw the same error on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> RESOLUTION:
>
> To resolve this issue, in the text I assigned to the cell, I replaced single quotes with double quotes, and because of this, had to escape the '$' and ' " ' characters. I also ADDED single quotes around "Report" (The table name from which data is being pulled) each time it came up within the text.
>
> It ended up looking like this, and running fine:
>
> ```
> $StatisticsSheet.Cells.Item($row,$column) = "=COUNTIFS('Report'!E2:E200000,B`$3,'Report'!G2:G200000,`"UserMailbox`")"
> ```
>
> Still not sure why this error occurred-the code had worked every week prior to this! Before changing the script and finding the resolution, I tested it on multiple machines (5+) and it threw the error mentioned in the title every single time.

Answer (score -1):

this is very simple issue, which in range put the values like

```
ExcelSheet.Cells.Range("A1:A1").Value = "'asdf"
```