# VB.net HRESULT: 0x800A03EC (excel) when Copying

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm attempting to copy data from excel workbook to another, but I'm getting at HRESULT: 0x800A03EC when trying to copy.

I've have read in detail and tried everything in an earlier post [HRESULT: 0x800A03EC on Worksheet.range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099770/hresult-0x800a03ec-on-worksheet-range)

Everything except changing the properties on the excel applications in the DCOM config (I didn't see the excel application)

Below is the code and error is happening in the bold.

```
    Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
    Dim newxlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkBooks As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
    Dim newxlworkbooks As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim newxlworkbook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim newxlworksheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing

    Dim String2Search4 As String = "1000"  'String to search for.
    Dim ColumnNumber As Integer = 4  

    xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    newxlApp = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\spreadseet1.xlsx")
    newxlworkbook = newxlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\spreedsheet2.xlsx")
    newxlworksheet = newxlworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For X As Integer = 1 To xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count Step 1
        'check if the cell value matches the search string.
        If xlWorkSheet.Cells(X, ColumnNumber).value = String2Search4 Then
            MsgBox("Found " & String2Search4 & " in row " & X)
            Dim rowfound As String = (X.ToString + ":" + X.ToString)
            **xlWorkSheet.Copy(xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 2), newxlworksheet.Cells(1, 1))**
            newxlworkbook.Close()
            xlWorkBook.Close()
        End If
    Next
```

--Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your Copy syntax is incorrect:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 2).Copy(newxlworksheet.Cells(1, 1))
```

Comment: I tried the suggested code and got an error "Copy method of Range class failed'
So I  may have an error further upstream?

Comment: It looks like my previous syntax was for copy an entire sheet, thanks for the correction

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error, it seems using some wait time fixed it:

So when copy, try to use :

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
```