# Set Excel Cell value using C#

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I use the following code to set the cell value of an Excel file:

```
for (int i = 2; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < columnCount; j++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value = enrollmentDataGrid.Columns[j].GetCellContent(enrollmentDataGrid.Items[i]);
    }
 }
```

However I keep getting the

> Error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Why do I get this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: what is the extension of your excel sheet ?

Comment: @ArchitGoyal, it's xlsx

Comment: How many rows in the file ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099770/hresult-0x800a03ec-on-worksheet-range refer to the second answer

Comment: @ArchitGoyal, it depends on the datagrid. I wanted the application to export data into an Excel sheet on click of a button. So it's supposed to create a new Excel file and write to it

Comment: Also when I hardcode the data the code works fine, but when I use the code in the question it fails

Comment: I was simply experimenting so there were only 9 rows, I don't think it was the problem in your reference @ArchitGoyal

Comment: What are the values of `rowCount`, in particular, prior to entering this code loop?  (This may be crucially important when it is applied to Excel).

Comment: It's 9 @gravity

Comment: For debugging purposes, you should probably separate the code a little, figure out where your actual problem is.  var x = enrollment...; Value = x;  Which line fails, the get or the assignment.  Assuming it is the get, try var y = enrollment.Items[i], and then var x = GetCellContent(y);  Just straightforward debugging until you figure out exactly which part is giving you errors.  You indicated that hard coding works, now figure out which variable is causing issues and research that.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```
  try
            {

                saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save as Excel File";
                saveFileDialog1.FileName = "";
                saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files(2003)|*.xls|Excel Files(2007)|*.xls";
                if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application worksheet = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    worksheet.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                    worksheet.Columns.ColumnWidth = 20;
                    for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;

                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                        }

                    }
                    worksheet.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString());
                    worksheet.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
                    worksheet.Quit();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: the problem is I can't seem to use enrollmentDataGrid.Rows[I].Cells[j]. The "Rows" part does not exist

Comment: @YiQin it's Winforms or Wpf? Please add the corresponding tag

Comment: i edited above code.please check whether is  this you wanted

Comment: Appreciate the help, but I'm not using datagridview, just datagrid. Is it possible to apply datagridview methods to datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `Value2` property (not `Value`)

So, your code would be as the following:

```
for (int i = 2; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < columnCount; j++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value2 = enrollmentDataGrid.Columns[j].GetCellContent(enrollmentDataGrid.Items[i]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Still get the error after using Value2. But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/470089/Exception-from-HRESULT-x-A-EC-Error

> It seems, that you are not the only one:
>   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099770/hresult-0x800a03ec-on-worksheet-range[^].
>
> According to the post, this error is occurring when you work with an
>   old (xls) workbook opened in Excel 2007 or 2010. If this is the case,
>   try first to save the file as new format workbook, before you access
>   the cells.

Comment: I checked the Excel file generated after hard coding it, and it is an xlsx file. Also, there are only 9 rows in my sample data, so I guess this is not the answer to my problem. Still, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;

                    }



 for (int i = 0; i < rowCount -1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[i+2, j+1].Value2 = enrollmentDataGrid.Columns[j].GetCellContent(enrollmentDataGrid.Items[i]);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I write exporting into xls using wpf framework in C#. I also encounter with this issue and I solve it with following code.Try to see from this code

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workb = app.Workbooks.Open("c:\\Users\\Jack\\Documents\\Document1.xlsx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
            worksheet = workb.Sheets[1];
           // worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1];
            //worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
            //worksheet.Name = "birinchi";




            for (int i = 0; i < Table.Columns.Count; i++) 
            {
             //   worksheet.Cells[1, i+1] = Table.Columns[i].Header;

            }


                for (int i = 0; i < Table.Columns.Count; i++)
                {

                    for (int j = 0; j < Table.Items.Count; j++)
                    {
                        TextBlock b = Table.Columns[i].GetCellContent(Table.Items[j]) as TextBlock;
                        worksheet.Cells[j + 2, i + 1] = b.Text;
                        //MessageBox.Show(b.Text);

                    }
                }

                Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
                dlg.FileName = "Document";
                dlg.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
                Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
                if (result == true)
                {

                   workbook.SaveAs(dlg.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);



                }
                app.Quit();
```