# Excel version miss match exception

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I have a windows application and using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll, v14.0.0.0 to do Excel related operations.

My system has Office 2007. While executing VLOOKUP with conditional operator and or Saving excel file I am getting common error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occurred
  HResult=-2146827284
  Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

The same works well where I have office 2013. Issue is even with 2010.

What is the best solution for this type of exceptions? I need to support office 2007 and above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HRESULT: 0x800A03EC on Worksheet.range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099770/hresult-0x800a03ec-on-worksheet-range)

Comment: Mine is a different issue. It throws when I am doing xlRange.Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, Formula1: value);   value = "=IF($I$2=44,$Y$2:$Y$4,$S$2:$S$6)"

Comment: And it happens when I am trying to SaveAs