# Facing "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC," exception from a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application which writes data to excel sheet.
I have recently updated my system os from windows 7 to windows 10, After launching this WPF application in my local machine while writing data to excel sheet I am facing below exception.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
>      at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookClass.Save()

Previously, I did not face this error while writing data to excel in windows 7 machine.
I am only facing this issue in windows 10 machine.
Can you please suggest the resolution for this.

Any kind of help is highly thankful.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
>      at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookClass.Save()

Comment: You need to install the Excel Interop that is the same version as the Excel installed on your PC.  The Interop is put into the c:\Program Files folder.  You can download from msdn.  Are you using a new version of Microsoft Office on the Window 10 machines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HRESULT: 0x800A03EC on Worksheet.range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099770/hresult-0x800a03ec-on-worksheet-range)

Comment: @jdweng, Yes, I am using microsoft office 2016 version in my machine

Comment: Do you have an office license on the machine?  Are you creating an Excel sheet from scratch or opening an existing template and add data?  Can you do the same manually from Excel?  Microsoft Office Products uses the ACE driver as the backend for a database.  Excel is just a front end app that reads/writes database using ACE.  An office file is a collection of objects with same format.  So in Excel you can have Word and Power Point objects  Each object has a header which indicates the object type (excel worksheet) and a version number (like created in excel 2003).  This may be a version issue.

Comment: The version of ACE and the version of Interop need to be the same and you need an Office License.  The file is located : C:\Program Files\Common Files\system\ado\msado15.dll