# Introduce formula in Excel Cell with C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010, datatable, excel-interop

I am already using interops to convert a *Datable into a Excel file*, everything is ok **but when I try to insert in the excel a formula like this:**

=(0,5*E30)

I have an error but if I try to insert another one like this:

=(0*E30)

everything it's ok. I am inserting it like a String. So what can be happening? I can't understand why only for use a , I get that error.

```
Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800A03EC</Message><StackTrace>   en Intranet.InteropExcel.DataTableToExcel(DataTable DataTable, String ExcelFilePath) en C:\Desarrollo\VisualStudio2010\ImeApps\Buscador\Intranet\ExportToExcel.cs:línea 301
   en Intranet.Intranet.butExcel_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) en C:\Desarrollo\VisualStudio2010\ImeApps\Buscador\Intranet\Intranet.cs:línea 3306
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
```

So what can be happening?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099770/hresult-0x800a03ec-on-worksheet-range

Comment: Pls share your code and show us where it fails.

Comment: @Steve have not sense, how can be a limit if the project works with the formula =(0*E30) and not with =(0,5*E30)

Comment: @Eldar is simply, I'm just trying this Cells[j, i] = formulaCantidad; where formulaCantidad is a String like this =(0,5*E30)

Comment: I would think it was the comma, where it probably expects a full stop. The answer suggesting changing the culture may work.

Comment: @Steve yes, has to be the comma but if I need to use it, how can I put it into the formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Excel.Range rng = ActiveSheet.Cells[j, i] as Excel.Range;
rng.Formula = formulaCantidad;
```

The problem probably format provider. Try with value like this `0.5` Or set your number format by culture.

```
var cultureInfo = //get culture info local or named
rng.NumberFormat = cultureInfo.NumberFormat;
```

Comment: Thank you @Eldar for your help. I am doing this:
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("es-ES",false).NumberFormat;
                                Int64 myInt = -1234;
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(myInt.ToString("C",nfi));
                                nfi.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 4;
                                Console.WriteLine(myInt.ToString("C", nfi));

And I get: -1.234,0000 €   What this means?

Comment: "C" means currency, but as you can see "**,**" is the decimal separator for "es-ES" culture. if you want to specify it manually you can set it `nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";`