# AutoHotKey - How to Get the Row Number of the Last Used Row in Column (From the Bottom Up)?

Tags: excel, autohotkey

Seems pretty straightforward, but am not having any success.

Pretty simple, using AHK, I want to get the number of the last row in a worksheet with a value in it, going from the bottom up. I can't go top down because some rows are blank, so has to be bottom up.

My code loops through all files in a selected folder (which only contain excel files), opens them, then tries to set the print area based on how many rows are used in the file. If it's <= 43 rows, set the print area to 43rd row, if it's more, set the print area to that row.

My code for `test.ahk` looks like this:

```
FileSelectFolder, WhichFolder  ; Ask the user to pick a folder.

Loop, %WhichFolder%\*.*
{

    Xl := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
    Xl.Workbooks.open(A_LoopFileFullPath)       ; open workbook
    Xl.Visible := 1                             ; make Excel Application visible

    Xl.DisplayAlerts := False

    ; First check if it's the dumb file that opens first, not part of the folder
    if xl.ActiveWorkbook.Name = "test.ahk" {
        xl.Quit()
        continue
        }

    ; Wait for the workbook to open
    Sleep, 2000

    ; Always start on the first worksheet
    Xl.Worksheets(1).Activate

    ; Now find the last used row for the print area
    ; If the last used row is on page 1, set it to the 43rd row

    lastRow := xl.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ;MsgBox, %lastRow%


    ; Set the print area
    if lastRow <= 43 {
        xl.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea := "A1:K43" 
    else {
        xl.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea := "A1:K"lastRow
    }



    ; Wait to close the script if you want for testing
    Sleep, 20000


    ; Close and save the workbook
    xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close(1)

    Xl.DisplayAlerts := True


}
ExitApp
```

...and I'm getting this error:

[image: Error]

I've tried lots of other combinations of trying to get the last row with a value in it too, but have had no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099770/hresult-0x800a03ec-on-worksheet-range Lots of things that could go wrong but ... one answer says indexing starts at 1. Is it possible there are no rows and you are asking Excel for `A0`?

Comment: Also `Xl.Worksheets("FIRE EXT.")` appears in your error but not the code you posted.

Comment: I managed to find a solution. Will post now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

UDPATE!

Found a working formula thanks to the help above:

```
xlUp := -4162
BottomRow := xl.Sheets(1).Rows.Count
LastRow1 := xl.Sheets(1).Range("B" BottomRow).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Did you mean `("B" & BottomRow)`? The ampersand seems to be missing.

Comment: @EndreBoth Negative. It works without the & sign. I'm not sure if the & throws an error or not, but without it, the code seems to tie "B" and then the number right after it nicely. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, apologies. I mixed up AHK and VBA syntax.