# Problem with ExportAsFixedFormat , Excel proccess not closing

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel-interop

We have a code that exports some data to excel, then uses that excel file to generate a pdf file using the exportAsFixedFormat function. Now it is failing with system exception regularly.

the below is the code

```
oBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF,
                      paramExportFilePath, paramExportQuality,
                      paramIncludeDocProps, paramIgnorePrintAreas,
                      paramFromPage, paramToPage, paramOpenAfterPublish)

        ' Close book
        oBook.Close()
        '
        'Exit Excel
        oExcel.Quit()
```

below is the exception error we are getting

> System.Exception: System.Exception:
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception
> from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC     at
> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType
> Type, Object Filename, Object Quality, Object IncludeDocProperties,
> Object IgnorePrintAreas, Object From, Object To, Object
> OpenAfterPublish, Object FixedFormatExtClassPtr)

Comment: Are you running this on a server? Also, why is this tagged .Net when its not VSTO its VBA?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099770/hresult-0x800a03ec-on-worksheet-range

Comment: `0x800A03EC` is a generic exception which means *what's that?* | *can't find it* | *nope, can't do* etc. Check the path, for example. The other parameters are unknown except `XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF`. The last one is missing. -- If you just have `oBook.Close()` and `oExcel.Quit()`, the Excel Process won't quit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.