Set an excel cell/range formula which contains quotation mark error. (0x800A03EC))
I use interop.excel library.
I want to set this string to the formula of some excel range: =HA(VAGY(C2="83V";C2="8U";C2="9V");"nem";"igen")
English: =IF(OR(C2="83V";C2="8U";C2="9V");"no";"yes")
After I copied it into visual studio backshashes were automatically added to the string:
"=HA(VAGY(C2=\"83V\";C2=\"8U\";C2=\"9V\");\"nem\";\"igen\")"
/* Set formulas in kifiz sheet*/
string formula1 = "=HA(VAGY(C2=\"83V\";C2=\"8U\";C2=\"9V\");\"nem\";\"igen\")";
ExcelMethods.setColumnFormula(kifiz, 2, 35, lastIndexKifiz, formula1);
//ExcelMethods is my class which makes me the work easier.
//setColumnFormula contains these line:
 myRange.Formula = formula; //i get the error in this line
/*---*/

I get 0x800A03EC error.
Formulas which don't contain quotation mark works fine.
Can you help me? :D
I tried double quotation marks.
Full error message:
See the end of this message for details on invoking
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
************** Exception Text **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): 0x800A03EC
at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Object[] aArgs, Boolean[] aArgsIsByRef, Int32[] aArgsWrapperTypes, Type[] aArgsTypes, Type retType)
at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.set_Formula(Object )
at ExcelMethods.setRangeFormula(Worksheet ws, Int32 startRow, Int32 startColumn, Int32 endRow, Int32 endColumn, String formula) in C:\Users\meszaros.joshua\source\repos\KarEsTartalekLista\KarEsTartalekLista\Methods.cs:line 84
at ExcelMethods.setColumnFormula(Worksheet ws, Int32 startRow, Int32 column, Int32 endRow, String formula) in C:\Users\meszaros.joshua\source\repos\KarEsTartalekLista\KarEsTartalekLista\Methods.cs:line 89
at KarEsTartalekLista.Form1.uzsgyi_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\meszaros.joshua\source\repos\KarEsTartalekLista\KarEsTartalekLista\Form1.cs:line 103
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(HWND hWnd, MessageId msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)

the backslashes are there to escape the quotation marks in C# string litteral, they are needed. This is indeed the same string that is above (just pause the execution and peek at the variable value to confirm). What is the full error message that you get?

Full error message:

please put in the question itself (Edit button)

Not sure whether it is a locale issue (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68556722/7274479). I would suggest trying to rule that out with a small sample using the translator add-in. For example =IF(OR(C2="83V",C2="8U",C2="9V"),"nem","igen").

Ahhhh it worked me, I tried it in english syntax, and worked fine.

Happy to hear it!
